# Placing legend on RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, regions, legending

I have the following 3D plot

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x > 1 && y > 0.5 && 
  z > 0.25 && (x + y > 1.7) && (y + z > 0.9) && (x + z > 1.5) && 
  x + y + z > 2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Green, 
 PlotLegends -> "Region", 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[C, 1]], HoldForm[Subscript[C, 2]], 
   HoldForm[Subscript[C, 3]]}, AxesStyle -> Thick, BoxStyle -> Thick, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black, Bold}]
```

This generates a legend label "Region" that lies outside the 3D plot. If I try to use LegendPosition->{0,0}, I get an error. How do I get the legend to sit inside the 3D plot box, in the white region and not outside the box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution using `Placed`[text, *coords*]

It helps to read the documentation for [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html), under **Details**, you can read

> `Placed[lspec,…]`   specify placement of legend

So you can use [`Placed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html)

[image]

Also notice that a well-indented code is easier to read.

```
RegionPlot3D[
  And[
      x > 1, y > 0.5, z > 0.25,
      x + y > 1.7, 
      y + z > 0.9,
      x + z > 1.5,
      x + y + z > 2
  ]
  , {x, 0, 3}
  , {y, 0, 3}
  , {z, 0, 3}
  , PlotPoints -> 100
  , BoundaryStyle -> None
  , Mesh -> None
  , PlotStyle -> Green
  , PlotLegends -> Placed["Region",Center] (* <-- See here *)
  , AxesLabel -> {
     HoldForm[Subscript[C, 1]]
   , HoldForm[Subscript[C, 2]]
   , HoldForm[Subscript[C, 3]]
  }
  , AxesStyle -> Thick
  , BoxStyle -> Thick
  , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black, Bold}
]
```

[image]

Or you can be more specific with the [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) and position

```
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Text[Style["Region",Bold,Red,25]],{0.3,0.5}]
```

[image]

## Other solutions

Other answers use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) and could have used also [`Overlay`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html) to combine various plots. From those I like the most the use of [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) or alternatively [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html), depending in which order you want things stacking.

Answer (score 6):

```
plot = RegionPlot3D[
  x > 1 && y > 0.5 && 
   z > 0.25 && (x + y > 1.7) && (y + z > 0.9) && (x + z > 1.5) && 
   x + y + z > 2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  PlotLegends -> "Region", 
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[C, 1]], HoldForm[Subscript[C, 2]], 
    HoldForm[Subscript[C, 3]]}, AxesStyle -> Thick, BoxStyle -> Thick,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black, 
    Bold}];
```

- We note that `plot[[2,1]]` is the `PlotLegends` and we `Inset` it into 3D.

```
Show[plot[[1]], 
 Graphics3D[{Inset[Style[plot[[2, 1]], Red], {.5, .5, 2}, Automatic, 
    Scaled[{.2, .1}]]}]]
```

[image]

- We can test another example which use several legends.

```
plot = RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 <= 1, x^2 + z^2 <= 1, 
    y^2 + z^2 <= 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}, PlotRange -> 3];
Show[plot[[1]], 
 Graphics3D[
  Inset[plot[[2, 1]], {-2, -2, 2}, Automatic, Scaled[{.2, .2}]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may either insert a text in your plot using `Epilog`. For this purpose 2D coordinates from 0 to 1 are used:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x > 1 && y > 0.5 && 
  z > 0.25 && (x + y > 1.7) && (y + z > 0.9) && (x + z > 1.5) && 
  x + y + z > 2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Green, 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[C, 1]], HoldForm[Subscript[C, 2]], 
   HoldForm[Subscript[C, 3]]}, AxesStyle -> Thick, BoxStyle -> Thick, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black, Bold}, 
 Epilog -> Text[Style["asas", FontSize -> 22], {0.15, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Or you can insert some text as an independent 3D item using `Show`. In this case the text is placed at an 3D position:

```
pl = RegionPlot3D[
  x > 1 && y > 0.5 && 
   z > 0.25 && (x + y > 1.7) && (y + z > 0.9) && (x + z > 1.5) && 
   x + y + z > 2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[C, 1]], HoldForm[Subscript[C, 2]], 
    HoldForm[Subscript[C, 3]]}, AxesStyle -> Thick, BoxStyle -> Thick,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black, 
    Bold}]; Show[pl, 
 Graphics3D[Text[Style["asas", FontSize -> 22], {0.5, 0.5, 2}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: How is your second solution different from the one offered by @cvgmt? (+1)

Comment: I used "Text" not "Inset"